# excel macro - reading filenames in a folder

Tags: excel, macros, directory, filenames

I am trying to send files in a folder via macro but `Dir()` is not reading the files.

[image]

[image]

Code is :

```
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fldName As String
Dim sName As String
Dim email As String


fldName = FolderName
i = 0

sName = Dir(fldName)
MsgBox Len(fldName)
MsgBox Len(sName)

Do While Len(sName) > 0

    Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objMail
        .To = email
        .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
        .Attachments.Add (fldName & sName)
        .Display ' .send
    End With

    sName = Dir
    i = i + 1

Loop
```

I even tried:

```
fldName = Chr(34) & FolderName & Chr(34)
```

But it didn't help.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: What value do you have in the variable Foldername? It seems judging from Dir() returning "" that it is not a string equal to a foldername on your drives

Comment: @MLind the variable (as you can see in the picture above) is coming from 

`FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\" & "Dosyalar - " & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & " " & DateString`

Comment: anyone, any ideas ?

Comment: "Dir()" comes with default or do i need to add any library reference ?

Comment: What abt experimenting a bit w dir()? Like what does dir("c:") return etc. Im still not convinced u are referring right to the library u r thinking of, how many " " or tabs are there btween the other signs, long "-" or prdinary minus, you know?